# Excel VBA Array Loop Troubleshooting: Using Redim and UBound, 1- and 2-dimensional arrays

Tags: vba, excel

I came here from [Stackover Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49308242/my-excel-macro-is-working-extremely-slow/49308558?noredirect=1#comment85620443_49308558) to doing faster macro. I got answer but this code not working and i am asking to you, (i tried to fix)

```
   Sub Faster_Method()

Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim Prc1 As String
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
Dim Search_Terms() As Variant
Dim CopiedData() As Variant

objIE.Visible = True


Search_Terms() = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A121").Value
ReDim CopiedData(1 To UBound(Search_Terms) + 1)

For a = 1 To UBound(Search_Terms) + 1

objIE.navigate "https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&app=578080_2&sort=lh&search_item=" & Search_Terms(a)
Do: DoEvents: Loop Until objIE.readyState = 4
Prc1 = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("item-amount")(0).innerText
CopiedData(a) = Prc1

Next

ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(UBound(CopiedData), 2)).Value = CopiedData

objIE.Quit

End Sub
```

**And the error is :** `run time error '9' subscript out of range`
**Debug is :** `objIE.navigate "https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&app=578080_2&sort=lh&search_item=" & Search_Terms(a)`

**Fixed**

```
   Sub Faster_Method()

Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim Prc1 As String
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
Dim Search_Terms() As Variant
Dim CopiedData() As Variant


Dim y As Integer
objIE.Visible = True


Search_Terms = Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A121").Value)

ReDim CopiedData(LBound(Search_Terms) To UBound(Search_Terms))


y = 1


For a = LBound(Search_Terms) To UBound(Search_Terms)
objIE.navigate "https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&app=578080_2&sort=lh&search_item=" & Search_Terms(a)
Do: DoEvents: Loop Until objIE.readyState = 4
Prc1 = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("item-amount")(0).innerText
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & y).Value = Prc1

y = y + 1

Next

ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(UBound(CopiedData), 2)) = Application.Transpose(CopiedData)

objIE.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: remove the `+1` from the for `For a = 1 To UBound(Search_Terms)`

Comment: Try `Search_Terms(a,1)`.

Comment: **1)** i tried `For a = 1 To UBound(Search_Terms)` - same error **2)** and i tried `For a = 1 To UBound(Search_Terms(a,1))` - same error

Comment: The `Search_Terms(a,1)` does not go in the UBound. It replaces the `Search_Terms(a)` on the `objIE.navigate` line

Comment: My comment was in relation to the line `objIE.navigate`. You need Scott's change too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems.

```
Search_Terms() = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A121").Value
```

The above code creates a 2-D array of Search_Terms(1 to 121, 1 to 1). This can be verified with,

```
debug.print lbound(Search_Terms, 1) & " to " & ubound(Search_Terms, 1)
debug.print lbound(Search_Terms, 2) & " to " & ubound(Search_Terms, 2)
```

Next you attempt to reshape a new array with,

```
ReDim CopiedData(1 To UBound(Search_Terms) + 1)
```

This converts the 2-D array to a new blank 1-D array of CopiedData(1 to 122).

Now you go into a loop.

```
For a = 1 To UBound(Search_Terms) + 1
```

The ubound here is the first rank (e.g. 1 to 121). You cannot go to Search_Terms(122, 1) because it doesn't exist. So when *a* becomes 122 the following crashes with run time error '9' subscript out of range.

```
objIE.navigate "https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&app=578080_2&sort=lh&search_item=" & Search_Terms(a)
```

**Possible solution(s)**

```
Search_Terms = application.transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A121").Value)
```

Creates a 1-D array of Search_Terms(1 to 121).

```
ReDim CopiedData(LBound(Search_Terms) To UBound(Search_Terms))
```

Reshape the target array to the same dimensions.

```
For a = LBound(Search_Terms) To UBound(Search_Terms)
```

Don't go outside of the Lower Boundary or the Upper Boundary.

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(UBound(CopiedData), 2)) = application.transpose(CopiedData)
```

You transposed the A1:A121 to get it into a 1-D array. It makes sense you need to transpose an identical 1-D array to put it back into B1:B121.

Comment: i do not understand how to fix it

Comment: it fixed but `CopiedData(a) = Prc1` not working. itsnot writing to excel

Comment: i dont receive error just it dont write the result on excel

Comment: Did you transpose CopiedData back into the worksheet like I suggested above?

Comment: yes it opens web sites correctly. just writing results arenot working.

Comment: i add the macro at question

Comment: i try to chance this code but i have a problem could you take a hand ? information link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323220/redim-lbound-changing-range?noredirect=1#comment85649467_49323220):
`Search_Terms = Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A121").Value)`
**to:**
`Search_Terms = Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A50").Value)`

Answer (score 0):

There may be an issue with the result of getElementsByClassName not being compatible with CopiedData().  I suggest eliminating CopiedData() and saving prc1 directly to Excel cells to see if that eliminates the wrong data type error.

Comment: ... or at least stepping through with F8 and examining the changing value of Prc1 and CopiedData with Watches in the VBE.