# Redim Lbound ( Changing Range )

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm new to vba and i am try to get price. The macro is :

```
    Sub GetPrice()
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim Prc1 As String
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    Dim Search_Terms() As Variant
    Dim CopiedData() As Variant
    Dim y As Integer
    objIE.Visible = False


    Search_Terms = Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A50").Value)
    ReDim CopiedData(LBound(Search_Terms) To UBound(Search_Terms))

    y = 2
    For a = LBound(Search_Terms) To UBound(Search_Terms)


    objIE.navigate "https://Example.com/?loc=shop_search&app=578080_2&sort=lh&search_item=" & Search_Terms(a)
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until objIE.readyState = 4
    Prc1 = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("item-amount")(0).innerText
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & y).Value = Prc1


    objIE.navigate "http://Example2.com/market/search?appid=578080&q=" & Search_Terms(a)
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until objIE.readyState = 4
    Prc1 = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("market_table_value")(1).getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & y).Value = Prc1


    Dim i As String
        Dim k As String
        i = "TL"
        k = ""
        Columns("D").Replace what:=i, replacement:=k, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False


    y = y + 1
    Next

    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(UBound(CopiedData), 2)) = Application.Transpose(CopiedData)

    objIE.Quit
    End Sub
```

When i try to chance:
`Search_Terms = Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A121").Value)`
to:
`Search_Terms = Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A50").Value)`

its coming to A50 and deleting the all results in excel and stop. What should i do ? Can u explain and write correct codes ?

Comment: "and deleting the all results in excel and stop" What do you mean by deleting all results? What cells are deleted? Stopping is what your code is doing correctly, as it runs to the end of the `Search_Terms` Variant per `For a = LBound(Search_Terms) To UBound(Search_Terms)`

Comment: in B colomn are deleted and just last result staying in B colomn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code line:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(UBound(CopiedData), 2)) = Application.Transpose(CopiedData)
```

... was originally designed to put the values from CopiedData back into the worksheet. However you are not populating CopiedData anymore; you are using Prc1 to write values back to the worksheet.

Delete or 'comment out' the above code line.